# Can someone explain me this regex in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

There's a program that use a regex and somehow I can't manage to understand it.

The code goes +- like this:

```
@listOfIds = &methodToGetIDs();
foreach my $id (@listOfIds){
    if($class =~ /gen/ig){
        #does stuff
    }
}
```

What I understand is that if `$class` has `"gen"` then it will get into the `if{}` but sometimes it won't get into it, so I put an else to see what was happening and the code end up like this:

```
my $class = "genes";
foreach my $id (@listOfIds){
    if($class =~ /gen/ig){
        print $class."\n"; #to see the value of class
    }else{
        print "!!!".$class."\n";   #to see the difference if there's any
    }#miss this wooops!
}
```

Guess what? the output was like this:

```
genes
genes
!!!genes
genes
genes
!!!genes
genes
genes
!!!genes
```

If the value of `$class` doesn't change then why does it gets into the else clause? Guess I don't understand regular expressions at all. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using the `/g` option. From [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) :

> In scalar context, each execution of `m//g` finds the next match, returning true if it matches, and false if there is no further match. The position after the last match can be read or set using the `pos()` function; see pos. A failed match normally resets the search position to the beginning of the string, ...

So, you are getting a match the first time you look at the string. Then, the next time you are starting after the position of the first match. I.e. the position is not reset to the start of the string, it continues on where the first match occurs.

The `/g` flag is used to indicate you want to match *all* the times you can in the string. That is useful for counting how many times a substring occurs in the string. In your case, you are testing to see if the pattern matches at all, true, and if it does, do something. You don't need the `/g` flag in this case.

```
my $class = "genes";

foreach my $id (1..6){ 
    if($class =~ /gen/ig){
        print $class."\n"; #to see the value of class
    }else{
        print "!!!".$class."\n";   #to see the difference if there's any
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
genes                                                                                                                                                                           
!!!genes                                                                                                                                                                        
genes                                                                                                                                                                           
!!!genes                                                                                                                                                                        
genes                                                                                                                                                                           
!!!genes
```

while if you remove the `/g` flag you get:

```
genes                                                                                                                                                                           
genes                                                                                                                                                                           
genes                                                                                                                                                                           
genes                                                                                                                                                                           
genes                                                                                                                                                                           
genes
```

Comment: Thank you charming gentleman, now I understand, now I need to ask why he wrote it like that and what was he trying to achieve, anyway, thanks all for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

The [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) manpage reads:

> In scalar context, each execution of m//g finds the next match,
>   returning true if it matches, and false if there is no further match.

Since `if` evaluates the condition in scalar context in your expression, every time it'll first return true, and then false as there are no further matches (I don't understand why it prints twice, and your code doesn't compile).

But note that:

```
if ( $class =~ /gen/i ) {
```

will *always* be true in your example, since `$class = "genes"` and doesn't appear to change. Did you mean to check `$id` instead?

At any rate, the `/g` modifier doesn't seem appropriate for your code.

Comment: No sir, it evaluates $class, and that's what I don't understand, why does it evaluate it if $class won't change, it's a code that I didn't write but that I need to understand since I need to replicate it but for python.

Edit: I miss one }, thanks for telling me